# Drag and Drop photo merge

Tags: php, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, desktop

This is a pretty broad question but something I'd like input on. I am attempting to create an interface where users can drag a photo from their desktop into a canvas in the browser. That canvas would have a fixed image in it already (acting as a watermark). I'd like the user to be able to drag and scale their image in the canvas until they are satisfied, then be able to save the image. The idea behind this being almost like a photo bomb but they choose a photo to merge theirs with.

I have done some research on using HTML5 canvas and also on using jQuery/PHP for the task but haven't decided which route to take yet.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You will need to use HTML5 Canvas, Jquery(or javascript) for sure. PHP would only be needed if you want to save the image or the canvas in a database or on a server.

Comment: goes a little off topic. could you bring out more what you have found so far and maybe ask pros and cons for those plus additional input